# Word clouds made by using more columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, word-cloud

I would need to create separate words cloud based on specific values.
I have a dataset that looks like:

```
     Date       Account   Message                                   Category
0   01/01/2020  412       nan                                          A
2   01/01/2020  214       nan                                          A
3   01/01/2020  53  There are plenty of foods                          C
4   01/01/2020  53  'Now that we've fought off oxidative damage        C
5   01/01/2020  214 Eggs are a very nutritious food                    B
6   01/02/2020  654 Unexplained cycle of AES is killing children       A
7   01/02/2020  41  Green tea contains flavonoids...                   B
```

I would like to create word clouds based on Account and Category separately, by date.

For example:

I would like to have a first group to plot as follows:

*By Account and date*

- All messages by 412 (i.e. only one message)
- All messages by 214 (i.e. two messages)
- All messages by 53 (i.e. two messages)
- All messages by 654 (i.e. only one)
- All messages by 41 (i.e. only one)

Then another group as follows:

*By Category and date*

**01/01**

- All messages by Category A (i.e. two messages from 412 and 214, respectively) on 01/01
- All messages by Category B (i.e. only one message from 654) on 01/01
- All messages by Category C (i.e. two messages from 53) on 01/01

**01/02**

- All messages by Category A (i.e. one message from 654) on 01/02
- All messages by Category B (i.e. one message from 41) on 01/02

(no messages by Category C on 01/02)

I think the approach should be the same as it needs a `groupby`.
For plotting the word cloud I have been trying to use the following code

```
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

def create_cloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='black',
        stopwords=stopwords,
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40, 
        scale=3,
        random_state=1
    ).generate(str(data))

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(20, 20)
    plt.axis('off')
    if title: 
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)

    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.show()


    new_data.groupby('Date').apply( # this is where I group by Date
        lambda x: create_cloud(x.Message.tolist())
    )
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is it giving any error? Each groupby and plot will produce a new word cloud.

Comment: I have some problems in getting the word clouds by grouping as aforementioned. I am confusing on what I should group by to get the results

Comment: I am still not getting the question, When I use `df.groupby(['Account', 'Date']).apply(lambda x: create_cloud(x.Message.tolist()))`, I get 5 word clouds - 1st with the words in the Message of Account 41, 2nd with the words in the Message of the 2 rows with Account 53, 3rd for the words in the Message of the 2 rows with Account 214, 4th one for the row with Account 412 and the 5th one for the row with Account 654.  Is that what you are expecting when you want to group by Account and date?

Comment: I would expect to get 5 word clouds by account, independently from date; 3 word clouds, one per each category, for date 01/01; 2 per each category on 01/02

Comment: Ok. If you use the statement I have in my previous comment, does it work for you? It actually gives me 5 word clouds groped by account and date.